# bash when inside screen, output is truncated if does not fit in a line

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

**Outside screen -**

```
[j@firedesire rb]$ diff -bu root_es-US.pres root_es-MX.pres | sed -n "s/^-\([^=]*\)=.*/'\1'/p" |  tr "\\n" ","
'IMG.HEAD.LOGO.URL','LNK.COPYRIGHT.URL','LNK.FOOTSECURITY.URL','LNK.HEADHELP.URL','LNK.HEADYAHOO.URL','LNK.PRIVACY.URL','LNK.TOS.URL','STR.HEAD.LOGO.HEIGHT','STR.HEAD.LOGO.WIDTH','REG.TOS.MAIL.URL','UPGRADE.STR.AGREE.STATEMENT',[j@firedesire rb]$
```

**Inside screen -**

```
[j@firedesire rb]$ diff -bu root_es-US.pres root_es-MX.pres | sed -n "s/^-\([^=]*\)=.*/'\1'/p" |  tr "\\n" ","
'IMG.HEAD.LOGO.URL','LNK.COPYRIGHT.URL','LNK.FOOTSECURITY.URL','LNK.HEADHELP.URL','LNK.HEADYAHOO.URL','LNK.PRIVACY.URL','LNK.TOS.URL','STR.HEAD.LOGO.HEIGHT','STR.HEAD.LOGO.WIDTH','REG.TOS.MAIL.URL','UPGR
```

It gets cut off at **'UPGR** where line ends. What could be causing this problem, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is wider than your `screen`

You can force the output to wrap by piping it through `less -+S`, you'll have to use your arrow keys to view all of the output.

There's an option in `screen` to toggle wrapping on or off; you may have luck with that as well: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Wrap.html

Comment: adding wrap "on" to my screen rc fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Another method besides `less` is to pipe it through `cat`:

```
ps aux | cat
top | cat
```

That won't pause at every screenful, like `less` or `more` would do, but when programs would otherwise halt until it receives user input, when they detect that their output is being piped to another process, they just dump out the results and keep going.

I use this a lot with external diff programs attached to my *git* or *svn* flags: `git diff | cat` keeps feeding my diff program all the extra files after the first one, while `git diff` by itself doesn't.